# How to get the fmtcount ordinal(num) suffix?

Tags: fmtcount

The `fmtcount` package provides the `\ordinalnum{⟨number⟩}` command which displays `⟨number⟩` followed by its suffix, the latter depending on the current (`babel` or `polyglossia`) language. For instance in English:

- `\ordinalnum{1}` gives "1<sup>st</sup>",
- `\ordinalnum{2}` gives "2<sup>nd</sup>",
- `\ordinalnum{3}` gives "3<sup>rd</sup>",
- `\ordinalnum{4}` gives "4<sup>th</sup>",
- ...
- `\ordinalnum{20}` gives "20<sup>th</sup>",
- `\ordinalnum{21}` gives "21<sup>st</sup>",
- `\ordinalnum{22}` gives "22<sup>nd</sup>",
- `\ordinalnum{23}` gives "23<sup>rd</sup>",
- `\ordinalnum{24}` gives "24<sup>th</sup>",
- etc.

I'd like to have a command, say `\foo{⟨number⟩}`, that prints only the suffix of `\ordinalnum{⟨number⟩}`. For instance in English:

- `\foo{1}` should give "<sup>st</sup>",
- `\foo{2}` should give "<sup>nd</sup>",
- `\foo{3}` should give "<sup>rd</sup>",
- `\foo{4}` should give "<sup>th</sup>",
- ...
- `\foo{20}` should give "<sup>th</sup>",
- `\foo{21}` should give "<sup>st</sup>",
- `\foo{22}` should give "<sup>nd</sup>",
- `\foo{23}` should give "<sup>rd</sup>",
- `\foo{24}` should give "<sup>th</sup>",
- etc.

Comment: `\ordinalnum` has an optional argument is not expandable then, it can't be used that way as an input to `\foo`

Comment: Not without extensive surgery on `fmtcount`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé It's not a task I'd undertake. You basically have to get a copy of every `\@ordinal{M|F|N}<language>` macro where the number is not printed. Different languages have a very different way to define the localized commands.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a half-successful naive attempt at the box level. One sees that `ngerman` causes a problem because it does not use a box. I am sure with lualatex you can do something by comparing the node list for say `17` with the one for `\ordinalnum{17}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\def\languages{french,danish,english,ngerman,italian}

\usepackage[\languages]{babel}
\usepackage{fmtcount}


\newsavebox\Denis
\makeatletter

\def\DenisQuest #1{{%\showboxdepth10 \showboxbreadth10
     \setbox\z@\vbox{\ordinalnum{#1}\global\setbox\Denis\lastbox}}%
     \unhbox\Denis
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{xinttools}% only for the loop for the example
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\parindent 0pt

\xintFor #1 in {\languages} \do {%
\hrulefill #1 \hrulefill
\begin{multicols}{8}
  \begin{otherlanguage}{#1}
     \xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq {0}{31}} \do
      {\ordinalnum{##1} $\longmapsto$ \DenisQuest{##1}\par }%
  \end{otherlanguage}
\end{multicols}}


\end{document}
```

[image]